Order Quantity Formula with multiple pipeline shipments allowed
I'm working an inventory problem for a client where we're trying to identify optimal order size and safety stock value when we can have multiple shipments in the pipeline (long lead time). All the textbook examples I've seen assume just a single pipeline shipment at a time.  Any suggestions?

Is lead time deterministic or stochastic?

Prefer stochastic to reflect reality better but we'll use deterministic if it gives us a tractable formula.
